# como puedo empezar con angular si tengo un hosting en php y mysql

Tags: angular, mvc, hosting, cpanel

Deseo saber como puedo empezar con angular si tengo un hosting en php y mysql, intente subir un site aqui dejo el link mas no funcionó http://www.netfanely.com/sgsi-petramas/ busque en google y youtube, mas colocan temas mas avanzados, mayormente en ingles, quiero empezar de cero.

no quiero usar php, quiero usar angular con las vistas modelo y controlador(MVC) gracias por su atención.

Comment: angular en conclusion es un html comprimido a final de cuenta, no entiendo que tenga que ver en el host se igual forma se vera

Comment: intena hacer en la raiz del proyecto `ng build` y la carpeta `dist` publicarla

Comment: Php no tiene nada de que ver con angular, si en tu servidor tienes instalado mysql o php no hace que puedas o no trabajar con angular, este lugar es para preguntas concretas, deberias investigar un poco más antes de preguntar aquí

Answer (score 0):

Un proyecto Angular una vez "generado" consistirá en recursos que no requieren ser ejecutados por un servidor web, como si es el caso de los ficheros PHP. Es decir que **un proyecto creado con Angular consistirá de html, css, imágenes, javascript...** esto se descarga en el navegador del cliente y es donde se ejecuta.

Una vez generado un proyecto Angular, debes de poder abrirlo de forma local sin necesidad de arrancar un servidor web o node, simplemente accediendo a la raíz del proyecto generado y abriendo el fichero "index.html". Es este fichero junto con los ficheros que lo acompañan lo que trasladas al servidor.

#### ¿Cómo probar el servidor web?

Los servidores web pueden tener diferentes configuraciones, pero siempre hay un directorio donde sirves tu aplicación web, generalmente "htdocs" donde deberás colocar el fichero que  permite el acceso a tu aplicación, normalmente `index.html`.

Puedes probar cual es tu directorio de inicio subiendo un "index.html" con un contenido de prueba, por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Prueba
</body>
</html>
```

Esto, si todo está correcto te mostrará en el navegador el texto "Prueba" cuando accedas a tu dominio.

#### ¿Cómo generamos nuestra aplicación Angular?

Angular nos permite desarrollar aplicaciones compuestas de recursos estáticos: HTML, CSS, JS, etc.

Durante el desarrollo, usamos node para servir la aplicación Angular con el comando:

```
ng open
```

Para obtener la aplicación de forma que podamos, por ejemplo, desplegarla en un servidor usaremos:

```
ng build
```

Los ficheros necesarios estarán en el directorio "dist". Los ficheros contenidos es este directorio son los que subiremos al directorio raíz de nuestro servidor web. Antes de esto podemos probar si funciona en local abriendo el fichero "index.html" con el navegador.

Si la prueba local funcionó, sube el fichero "index.php" del proyecto que generaste con Angular, junto con el resto del contenido de la aplicación, al directorio *htdocs* (o el que corresponda) para que tu aplicación generada con Angular esté disponible en tu dominio.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, decirte que localmente si puedo ver la pagina, colocando estos comandos en consola >npm install @angular/cli y >ng serve --open, abre el documento en localhost:4200, mas en el hosting que alquilo, tiene un cpanel, no sabria como generar esos comandos, o tengo que subir todos los archivos despues de ejecutar esos comandos al hosting???

Comment: @F Pastor en local tu tienes un node y desarrollas el proyecto angular, es ahí donde ejecutas los comandos. Tras generar el proyecto con `ng build` lo que llevas al servidor son los ficheros generados dentro del directorio `dist`. Ya no vas a usar los comandos.